# Лицензия static google maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Здравствуйте.

Как вам наверное известно, у static google maps есть некоторый лимит запросов. Части карт мне нужно загружать постоянно однотипные. Так вот, собственно вопрос:

Можно ли сохранить изображения требуемых участков карты и положить всё это дело к себе на сервер и соответственно не обращаться больше к серверам google maps.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying.**
>
> ...
>
> (b)No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

И ещё пункт 10.1.1 (g). Так что, судя по всему, нет, нельзя.

Answer (score -1):

Можно! На PHP это делает функция [copy()](http://www.php.su/functions/?copy)

Comment: Да не в этом дело)
Мне просто интересно, можно ли просто сохранить изображения. Нарушится при этом что-то или нет.

Comment: Что нарушится если это статика?

Answer (score -1):

если речь идет об экономии трафика, то необходимо правильно настроить кэширование на сервере для картинок, тогда при повторном обращении клиентом к тому же участку карты сервер будет отдавать картинку из своего кэша.
это эффективно тогда, когда пользователи активно работают с какой-то одной не особо большой географической зоной.